# CSS Casing Ignored

Tags: css

For some reason, the featured articles in the right column are ignoring the '#elementtext' and '#elementtext:hover' attributes. Only 'p.element' and 'img.element' are showing.

Any ideas?

Thanks - Tara

**Bonus:** I'm also trying to get the 'p.element' text to float centrally (vertically and horizontally - while being left aligned) in the '#elementtext' boxes.

```
#elementtext {
        height: 90px;
        width: 150px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    background: #c3c3c3;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 5px;
}
p.element {
        height: 85px;
        width: 145px;
    padding: 2.5px 2.5px 2.5px 2.5px;
}
#elementtext:hover{
    background:#ff9999;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span is an inline element you cannot put tags in it 
add display:block  to your #elementtext

like this

```
#elementtext {
display:block;
height: 90px;
width: 150px;
margin-left: 1px;
background: #c3c3c3;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 5px;
}
```

edit i think you have class="elementtext"
so you put . infront of it not #

```
.elementtext {
display:block;
height: 90px;
width: 150px;
margin-left: 1px;
background: #c3c3c3;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it, you have multiple instances of elementtext.  If that is the case then these should be classes and not ids.  A css id should be unique throughout the page.

Try the following HTML:

```
<span class="elementtext">Test</span>
```

And the css:

```
 .elementtext {
    height: 90px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    background: #c3c3c3;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 5px;
}
p.element {
    height: 85px;
    width: 145px;
    padding: 2.5px 2.5px 2.5px 2.5px;
}
.elementtext:hover{
    background:#ff9999;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: .. It hasn't worked for some reason. It's just made a small box under the text...